# In Android material design, how can I make a label looks "clickable"?

Tags: android, material-design

Currently, I have the following legacy holo app.

[image]

In navigation drawer, please note that on the right **NEW** icon. When user clicks on the icon, they can either add new Watchlist, or new Portfolio.

So far, I would say the usability is pretty good. At least, I never receive support request, on how to add new Watchlist, or new Portfolio.

Recently, we are in the progress of migrating holo app to material app.

Here's my initial design.

[image]

Although I try to use

1. Different fonts for label **WATCHLIST** and **PORTFOLIO**
2. All CAP case.
3. Add a `+` text.

I still doesn't feel the labels are clickable. At least, compared to previous holo design, new users are more difficult to figure out how to add new Watchlist & new Portfolio.

Any suggestion, how I can further improve the design?

p/s Please take note that, having colorful short line above the label, is idea originated from Google Now :)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The convention I see most option in Google mobile apps is this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide me a "role model" app? As, so far, most of the app I encounter, are having read-only item in navigation drawer. I don't see much good examples, of able to create new item via navigation drawer.

Comment: Take at the sidebar menu in Google Inbox

Answer (score 1):

By using margin, dividers, and icons.

Check this out:

[image]